# faraday timeout error on rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an error that is this: `Faraday::TimeoutError: Net::ReadTimeout`

Heres the rake task which fails:

```
 Event.all.each do |row|
         date = row.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
         time = row.time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
         event2 = EventTable2.find_by('product_name ILIKE ? AND delivery_time ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ?', "%#{row.eventname}%", time, date)
         if event2.blank?
           event2 = EventTable2.find_by('product_name ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ?', "%#{row.eventname}%", date)
       end
       if event2.present?
       eurl = event2.merchant_product_id
     end
     if eurl.present?
         if eurl.length > 7
           row.update(event2: eurl, eventimage: event2.merchant_image_url)
         end
      end
    end
```

I'm wondering it its because i have `Event.all.each` I'm wondering if its taking too long on this and falling over?

Any help would be great (even if i need the rake task rewriting)

Thanks

Comment: You can set the timeout in Faraday when you create the connection (see the "usage" section in the readme: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday).  Try setting that an upping the values.  The other thing worth checking is how long does it take to execute your find_by statements.  Perhaps add some indexes to improve the speed.